# reading from a text file and printing every number right away gives different output than printing after reading all the file

Tags: c++

So I want to read number from a file, the file looks like so:

```
8
9 5 7 -5 13 -4 11
7 5 -3 12 -5 17 -3
25 7 12 -3 5 -5 7 -5 3
14 5 12 -3 10 -7 8
5 1 -40
33 5 15 -5 9 -3 8
11 5 -12 8 -5 12 -3
13 5 3 -4 25 -5 3
```

I need all the numbers, that are not on the first line and are not the first ones in the line, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int times[99];

int n, k, t;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("U1.txt");

    file >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        file >> k >> t;
        for (int j = 0; j < t; j++)
        {
            file >> times[j];
            cout << times[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        cout << times[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Outputting every single number while reading gives what I want:

```
7 -5 13 -4 11
-3 12 -5 17 -3
12 -3 5 -5 7 -5 3
12 -3 10 -7 8
-40
15 -5 9 -3 8
-12 8 -5 12 -3
3 -4 25 -5 3
```

For some reason my output after reading everything is like so (I don't mind about the 0s I know why they are here):

```
3 -4 25 -5 3 -5 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: You are overwriting the values in the array as you go along.  If you print everything at the end then you will only see the values from the last line (plus some values at the end from previous lines if those lines were longer).  You probably want either a 2D array, or you want to keep track of a an index that you can add to `j` so that you aren't starting at 0 when writing each line.

Comment: Can I suggest looking at this?  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Even after fixing that, your loop control limits are clearly different regardless. They're data-controlled in the first case, hard-coded to 99 in the second. Eventually that, too, is going to be an issue.

Comment: Plus of course, obligatory mention that you should be using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of a raw array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you start the inner loop, you reset j to 0, so you overwrite the contents previously written to your array after reading each line. This results in your array only containing the last line of your file.
You should maybe make another variable, initialize it once before the start of the outer loop and increment it inside the inner loop.